# Don't want to filter if field is empty/blank. [django queries]

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've added following query. and it works. Now I want to extend it.

```
    return self.model.objects.filter((
        Q(field1=F('p__field1')) |
        Q(field2=F('p__field2'))),
        user=user
    )
```

if `F('p__field1')` is `empty/blank`. Then I don't want to include this in filter `Q(field1=F('p__field1')`. (In other words, I don't to filter this.)

And same for `F('p__field2')`.

`field1` is a `ForeignKey` and `field2` is a `ManyToMany` field in both tables.

Any Idea? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that with an additional filter before or after that makes sure the fields aren't null.

```
model_filter = Q()
if self.model.p.field1:
    model_filter |= Q(field1=F('p__field1'))
if self.model.p.field2:
    model_filter |= Q(field2=F('p__field2'))
return self.model.objects.filter(user=user).filter(
    model_filter
)
```

Comment: thanks. I've updated the my query and question. Any idea on latest update? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're asking to build up the Q object dynamically. There's a number of SO questions and answers that explain how to do this. This is just one way.